React-Native Build Failed - Terminal
I create react-native project on my laptop and it builds successfully.
But with the same project I try to run it on my desktop pc but it gives an error build failed.
I updated gradle. I edited the sdks. I followed the documentation exactly. I have created a project with expo before. This is my first react-native CLI project
enter image description here
